# Angular : How to re arrange the Json object in Angular

Tags: angular

I need to get the output as below,

Input Json:

```
var arrayList = [{"id":"100","country":"india","name":"ram"},
                 {"id":"100","country":"india","name":"sita"},
                 {"id":"100","country":"india","name":"lakshman"},
                 {"id":"109","country":"usa","name":"jhon"},
                 {"id":"109","country":"usa","name":"adam"},
                 {"id":"110","country":"uk","name":"andy"}]
```

Expected Output Json Object:

```
 expectedOutputJson=["1":"ram":{"id":"100","country":"india","name":"ram"},
                "sita":{"id":"100","country":"india","name":"sita"},
                "lakshman":{"id":"100","country":"india","name":"lakshman"}
            "2":"jhon":{"id":"109","country":"usa","name":"jhon"},
                "adam":{"id":"109","country":"usa","name":"adam"}
            "3":"andy":{"id":"110","country":"uk","name":"andy"}]
```

Tried with below code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular';
  arrayList = [{"id":"100","country":"india","name":"ram"},
                 {"id":"100","country":"india","name":"sita"},
                 {"id":"100","country":"india","name":"lakshman"},
                 {"id":"109","country":"usa","name":"jhon"},
                 {"id":"109","country":"usa","name":"adam"},
                 {"id":"110","country":"uk","name":"andy"}]
  };
```

// I need to declare my map something like below but i am not able to do it

```
private map = new Map<string, list<Map<string, list<Map<string, string>>>>();


constructor() {
    Object.keys(this.arrayList['values']).forEach(key => this.map.set(key, this.arrayList['values'][key]))
    console.log(this.map)
  }
}
```

Could any one can help me on this please.

Comment: your output isn't valid json. please fix

Answer (score 0):

your output isn't valid, hard to tell what you're after, but i think you're just trying to convert an array to an object keyed by index... which is a simple reduce operation...

```
   this.expected = this.arrayList.reduce((acc, v, idx) => {
     acc[idx] = v;
     return acc;
   }, {});
```

or if you really want a map, it's similar

```
   this.expected = this.arrayList.reduce((acc, v, idx) => {
     acc.set(idx.toString(), v);
     return acc;
   }, new Map());
```